# n-sided regular polygon

Tags: geometry

Can anyone help me on this? The method I used is to draw triangle, rectangular and so on, then try to find solution. But I feel it is not the best way and my answer seems wrong. Your help is deeply appreciated.

Problem: For how many values of n will an n-sided regular polygon have interior angles with integral degree measures?

Comment: The sum of the angles of an $n$-gon is $2\pi(n-2)$. So you are looking for all $n$ such that $360(n-2)/n$ is integer. Take it from there.

Comment: @LevBorisov:  It is really $(n-2)\pi$ but that is the right approach.  If you cut the $n-$gon into triangles there are $n-2$ of them and each contributes $\pi$

Comment: Compute the interior angles, maybe by drawing lines from the centre to the vertices. You should get that the interior angles of an $n$-gon are $180-\frac{360}{n}$. For what $n\ge 3$ is this an integer?  If you know a formula for the number of divisors of an integer $k$ in terms of the prime factorization of $k$, it will speed things up.

Comment: Oops, my mistake :)

Answer (score 1):

An n-sided regular polygon's interior angle sum should be 
$180(n-2)$, so the interior angles would each be $\frac{{180^\circ \left( {n - 2} \right)}}{n}$. Then, these angles would have an integral value if either $180°$ or $n-2$ is divisible by $n$, or both are divisible by $n$. By counting these, you should get an answer.

Comment: You just need the product of $180$ and $n-2$ to be divisible by $n$.  Take $n=8,$ which divides neither $180$ nor $6$

Comment: @DiscreteMath: The version $180-\frac{360}{n}$ of the angle size makes it easier to find all the answers, or to count them without listing.